# Java - Can't figure out which layout to use?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I had my layout perfect until I couldn't figure out how to make drag and drop work.  So to make the coding easier, I switched my labels on the bottom right side of my program to buttons to allow single clicking to generate an object in the main panel.

Now that I switched them, using BoxLayout, the buttons are not able to be sized for the image to fit perfectly in them, leaving edge space as seen in the photo.  I also have a horizontal scroll bar now which I didn't have before with the labels.

[image]

I have tried several different layouts to try and fix the size of these buttons, but I can't get things to work right.  I just need a vertical scroll bar and I want the buttons to be the exact size of the images, like they are in the panel above them.  I tried setting the layout to null like I have in all the other panels and using the setBounds() method and that works perfectly for placement, but then the scroll bar disappears and won't scroll.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:  Here is what happens when I use the null layout.

[image]

Comment: It's what our college taught us to use.  The question should be, why Java and not C++?  ;)

Comment: @KrisPurdy More flexibility when it comes to UI elements.

Comment: In your case, it's more why Swing and not HTML5? It's so much easier to design a user interface with CSS! Languages are all the same, but the frameworks supporting them are much more important to quickly build something.

Comment: I would much rather use VB but our assignment for class requires us to use Java and to not use generated code.  I think our professor probably hasn't made a GUI in 40 years and thinks it's simple to do one in Java.  I took the class to learn how to make GUIs but all we learn is history of them and what makes one look good, not how to create or code them. =/

Comment: @KrisPurdy check out QtQuick if you have not already--you'll be much happier if you have small projects like this that are not for a specific class. It is a lot more work to get rolling but the payoff is immense.

Comment: I use GroupLayout to layout components. It allows me to place components in whatever way I want. Its very cool. Netbeans also use GroupLayout in GUI builder.

Answer (score 2):

I'd really recommend that you use GridBag layout if you're using swing. The other layouts leave a lot to be desired. It is all a matter of preference and you can lay it out manually if you want--there's no right answer.

The reason I prefer GridBag (or MigLayout--to each their own) is that you have a concept of preferred size for the component and the concept of fills. It has been a while since I coded up Swing (and I'll try to keep it that way!) but you're basically looking for something like:

```
{
   //Pseudo Code, I'd have to go read the API again, I wrote a set of utilities so I    wouldn't have to think about it.
  GridBagConstraints constraints = ....;
  constraints.weightX = 1.0; //fill the area by X
  constraints.weightY = 1.0; //fill by Y
  constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; //or one...
  component.setPreferredSize(image.size());
  layout.add(component, constraints); 
}
```

Basically what you're doing is saying "use my preferred size as a minimum" but fill based on these rules.

The alternative--which doesn't use a layout is simply position the components yourself (there's absolutely nothing wrong with this).

```
{
  JPanel panel =...;
  panel.setLayout(null);

  ...
  myButton3.setX(0);
  myButton3.setY(2 * buttonHeight); //third button
  myButton.setSize(myButton.getPreferredSize()); //which I assume you set
  ...
  panel.add(myButton3);
  ...
}
```

Anyhow, there's a lot of options. Don't feel like you need to use a layout, write your own. You should care about these things and make it work but you shouldn't suffer. A layout is generally very simple to implement and you shouldn't be afraid to walk away from this.

All that said, GridBag will do what you want. Alternatively, Mig is great and has some nice GUI editors.

UPDATE -> -------------------------------
Here's a concise example--I sincerely do not advocate this style of programming, I just didn't want class spam for the example.

```
   package _tests;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Grids extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String ... args)
  {
    new Grids().setVisible(true);
  }

  public Grids()
  {
    //Null layout example
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(250, 300);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(285, 300)); //Windows 8 ~ border size + scrollbar
    setTitle("Test layouts");

    JPanel scrollTarget = new JPanel()
    {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      {
        setSize(250, 1000);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 1000));
        //setLayout(null); -- uncomment for absolute
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        int lastX = 0;
        int lastY = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
          final String label = "Button " + i;
          JButton tmp = new JButton()
          {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            {
              setText(label);
              setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200)); //Preferred
            }
          };

          tmp.setSize(tmp.getPreferredSize()); //What you're layout usually does..
          //add(tmp);
          //tmp.setLocation(lastX, lastY);
          //lastY += tmp.getHeight();

          add(tmp, getButtonConstraint(0, i));
        }
      }

    };

    add(new JScrollPane(scrollTarget));
    }



      private GridBagConstraints getButtonConstraint(int x, int y)
      {
        GridBagConstraints tmp = new GridBagConstraints();
        tmp.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        tmp.weightx = 1.0;
        tmp.weighty = 1.0;
        tmp.gridx = x;
        tmp.gridy = y;
        tmp.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;

        return tmp;
      }

}
```

Comment: I added a photo to the original post.  That's what happens when I use null layout.  I would prefer using that layout because I am making my window fullscreen and non-resizable and I can place things exactly where I want them. 

When I use null though, I can't get the scroll bars working.  I even forced it to use a scroll bar, but it doesn't put the little block in there you can drag to scroll with.

Comment: What's the size of you container panel? (The one containing the buttons?) You'll need to give it a preferred size and set it for the ScrollPane to know how to scroll it)

Comment: At the moment I have the panel not being declared a size.  I put the buttons on there at specific locations and I set the JScrollPane the size that you see in the picture.  If I set a size for the panel that is on the JScrollPane then it gets put on top of the scroll pane and you can't see the scroll bars.

Comment: I updated this example to show you how they both work. setPreferredSize is what you need to look at. What's probably happening (I can't be certain) is your panel isn't the size you think (inside the container) or the scroll pane is being clipped. Pull it out into a JFrame with a default layout and inspect it. I'd bet your scroll pane size isn't what you think it is.